# How to stop a gevent micro thread when it in a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, timeout, gevent

I have a problem and the situation was like code as below. The target function(wait) was in a while loop or spent a huge time, so I want to kill the micro thread. How to kill the thread1?

**Note** : The micro-thread of user may be a CPU bound operation (for example a while loop without any IO operation.)

```
import gevent
from gevent import Timeout

def wait():
    while(1):
        pass
    print 'end'


timer = Timeout(1).start()
thread1 = gevent.spawn(wait)

try:
    thread1.join(timeout=timer)
except Timeout:
    print('Thread 1 timed out')
```

Both of `gevent.killall()` and `thread.kill()` requires the `thread scheduler` to run, they will not kill the thread as we expected.

Comment: you can use gevent.killall() !

Comment: gevent.killall() will not work as expected, I have add some description in my question. Thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of unnecessary work there. You can simply pass the seconds as keyword argument to [`join()`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.Greenlet.join) like below:

```
>>> import gevent
>>> def wait():
...    while True:
...        print("In loop")
...        gevent.sleep(1) # To not fill the screen..
...       
>>>
>>> g = gevent.spawn(wait)
>>> g.join(timeout=5)
```

The following will kill the greenlet which is running `wait()` after 5 seconds. You *can't* catch the `Timeout` because [`join()`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.Greenlet.join) will catch it for you, and kill the greenlet silently as long as the timeout is the one it's excepting. The following is a snippet of [`join()`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.Greenlet.join) from the source of [`greenlet.py`](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/blob/master/gevent/greenlet.py)

```
try:
    t = Timeout.start_new(timeout)
    ... SNIP ...
except Timeout as ex:
    self.unlink(switch)
    if ex is not t:
        raise
```

You can kill a greenlet using [`kill()`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.Greenlet.kill) as well. I think this is the wrong approach here but I'll add the example anyway. The following will run the greenlet for 5 seconds and then kill it:

```
>>> g = gevent.spawn(wait)
>>> with gevent.Timeout(5, False):
...     g.join()
... g.kill()
...
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t say so clearly. I mean like a while loop but you didn’t have chance to add gevent.sleep(1) to let this greenlet sleep. Just like call a 3rd party library function and it didn’t response for a long time.

Comment: @user3611389 I don't think you can fix a long blocking issue by timing out a greenlet if net never gets to do a context switch.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, as you said, we have no change to timeout or kill a micro-thread for gevent since we have no chance to execute a context switch, we have to run non-cooperative thread or use system timer API instead. This answer helps to explain the reason why codes in the question will not work, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only work if the "wait" micro thread has the chance to switch. If you control the code of your thread you can achieve that for example by calling gevent.sleep. Otherwise if the code of your thread is implemented in python and uses IO operations you may try to monkey patch the python functions by:

```
from gevent.monkey import patch_all
patch_all()
```

this will allow your thread to switch when hits various IO operations.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but in case of CPU bound operation, the switcher has no chance to run. This answer don't solve the problem, thanks anyway.
I will describe my question in more detail after a while.

Answer (score -2):

I meet the same problem, I have to kill a greenlet thread(which has codes written by user).

**In case of CPU-Bound operation, Gevent's switch and Timeout will not work!**

We can not assume that user writes correct codes which has no dead-loop which has CPU-Bound operation.

Finally, I use "Signal" API to solve this problem.

Please refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

About Gevent's Switch and Timeout: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gevent/eBj9YQYGBbc

Codes below may be for you information.

```
from gevent.monkey import patch_all;patch_all()
import gevent
import time


def fucking_loop():
    while True:
        pass


def fucking_loop_with_timeout():
    with gevent.Timeout(10):
        while True:
            pass


def fail_to_kill():
    deadline = time.time() + 10

    thread = gevent.spawn(fucking_loop)

    while deadline > time.time():
        # gevent.sleep will switch out of main thread
        gevent.sleep(1)

    # This line of code will never been executed
    # because gevent will not switch to main thread.
    thread.kill()


def fail_to_kill_2():

    thread = gevent.spawn(fucking_loop)

    # Will never timeout because of the same reason
    fucking_loop_with_timeout()

    # This line of code will never been executed
    # because gevent will not switch to main thread.
    thread.join(timeout=10)
    thread.kill()


def kill_fucking_loop_works():
    import signal
    timeout = 10

    thread = gevent.spawn(fucking_loop)

    def kill_thread(*args, **kwargs):
        if not thread.dead:
            thread.kill(timeout=1)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, kill_thread)
    signal.alarm(int(timeout))
```